Best way to install Ubuntu Unity 24.04
For those who want to use Unity 24.04.
What is best:

Install default Ubuntu 24.04 and after install Unity environment?
or
Install directly Ubuntu Unity Flavor?
Thanks in advance for your advice.


Allow me a comment: I am 10 years enthusiastic about Ubuntu but my skills are not great. Therefore, I find it discriminatory for someone to put a "-1" to my question.
Do you prefer that users are left alone with their problem? FYI I searched unsuccessfully for the answer before publishing my post. Once again, thank you to karel.

Ubuntu Unity 24.04 continues to use Unity 7.7, which has undergone maintenance in order to have a working Lomiri variant. Ubuntu Unity 24.04 is stuck with X11 for the time being because of requirements for dependencies, including Nux, the UI toolkit used for rendering Unity 7's user interfaces. In order to minimize package management issues arising from these dependencies I recommend installing the Ubuntu Unity 24.04 flavor over installing the Unity desktop environment on a different flavor of Ubuntu.
